# Using raw DB to query but fails to run because sql string has an error

Tags: sql, laravel

Im new to using laravel and i have to query using the an sql string but the code fails to run because there is an error in the sql query 
The code is:

```
 $current_lat = $request->latitude;

  $current_lng = $request->longitude;

  $car_type = $request->car_type;
        $data=DB::table('artisantypes')->select(DB::raw('artisantypes.max_seat AS max_size,3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN(($current_lat - artisans.driver_lat) * pi()/180 / 2), 2)+ COS($current_lat * pi()/180 ) * COS(artisans.driver_lat * pi()/180) * POWER(SIN(($current_lng - artisans.driver_lng) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) )) as distance,artisans.driver_lat,artisans.driver_lng' ))
        ->leftjoin('artisans','artisantypes.id', '=','artisans.car_id' )
        ->where('artisantypes.id' ,'=', $car_type and 'artisans.status', '=' , 0)
        ->groupby('artisans.id')
        ->having('distance' ,'<', 25)
        ->orderby ('distance', 'ASC' )
        ->limit( 0,1)
        ->get();
```

The Error in got is :

```
 check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '= `artisantypes`.`id` = ? group by `artisans`.`id` having `distance` < ?
```

Comment: `where('artisantypes.id' ,'=', $car_type and 'artisans.status', '=' , 0)` this doesn't look right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot directly specify an AND in the where function.

change

```
->where('artisantypes.id' ,'=', $car_type and 'artisans.status', '=' , 0)
```

to

```
->where([
    ['artisantypes.id' ,'=', $car_type],
    ['artisans.status', '=' , 0],
])
```

Comment: But after correcting it,the query cant find $current_lat and $current_lng

Comment: Those are PHP basics. You cannot use a variable name inside single quotes. Use double quotes if you want to parse variables inside it.

'$current_lat' and "$current_lat" will give you different strings.